# How to alter program's hotkeys? (Whatsapp)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I am searching for a general solution to this question. For any given program that runs on windows 10, how I can disable or alter the hotkeys that it uses?
Some programs don't let the user to change the hotkeys (shortcuts) that they use. Is there anyway through registry or anywhere else to change them or at least disable them. Because sometimes they override the existing windows shortcuts.

Comment: Pressing the shortcut key, which program is started is which program sets the conflicting shortcut key. Then right click on the program icon, Properties->Shortcut. In the short key box, modify the program hotkey. For those programs that don't allow users to change hotkeys, you can try AHK recommended by Linus. If this still doesn't work, you can find more help from the provider of the program.

Comment: As it is currently written, this question is simply too broad to be answered well. Programs use and implement hot keys in different ways. Windows has its own way, and each program can have different ways. In order to make this question answerable, please use the EDIT button to name a specific program you wish to change the hot keys for.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a perfect answer to this since I am pretty sure that it depends on how the application is built.

However, you can run AutoHotkey to override or change the association with a key, making it do something else, or nothing at all. This workaround is applicable to most Windows applications.

AHK can be found [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and a great IDE to create scripts is [SciTE4AutoHotkey](http://fincs.ahk4.net/scite4ahk/).